# How to open a "window" in a modal?

Tags: rubymotion

I am creating an iOS app with the help of Rubymotion.
I am using a navigationController as a rootview and I need to open a window in a modal.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to open it on top of another UIViewController. So, push a UIViewController onto your UINavigationController and then use the `presentModalViewController:animated:` method:

```
navigation_controller.pushViewController(main_view_controller, animated: true)
main_view_controller.presentModalViewController(modal_controller, animated:true)
```

When you're done with it, dismiss it:

```
main_view_controller.dismissModalViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Comment: You'll need to create another UINavigationController, push your modal_controller into it, and present that. If you want, you can check out my ProMotion gem that makes these things a lot easier. http://www.clearsightstudio.com/insights/ruby-motion-promotion-tutorial/